# Call Rails Controller Action from Javascript not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to call a controller-action from javascript.

The chrome debugger shows the javascript being stepped into ok (so the js click event is triggered ok).

The controller action works if I use a HTML button to call it i.e. the /home/benefits/ page renders ok (so the controller action code in itself is functional).

It does not seem to work when I try call it via javascript - the development.log seems to show it has rendered the page, but my website page does not change to the /home/benefits/ page

I've read as many tutorials and related issues on OS but I'm stumped. Any help would be appreciated from this awesome SO community!  ;-)

CONTROLLER CODE:

```
  def set_analysis_input
     redirect_to home_benefits_path
  end
```

ROUTES.RB:

```
  get "trades/set_analysis_input"
```

HTML.ERB:   (1st line using html button is ok, 2nd line via JS does not work)

```
<%= link_to "Button to Call Action", trades_set_analysis_input_path, class: "btn btn-small btn-success" %>
<button id="button_to_call_controller_action">hello</button>
```

JS AT END OF HTML.ERB FILE:

console.log("Entered JS");

```
  $(document).on('click', '#button_to_call_controller_action', function() {
    url_string = "/trades/set_analysis_input";
    $.ajax({
       url:   url_string,
       type:  'get'
    });  
  });
```

END OF DEVELOPMENT.LOG FILE:

```
Started GET "/trades/set_analysis_input" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-15 12:47:44 +0000
Processing by TradesController#set_analysis_input as */*
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 38 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/home/benefits
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/home/benefits" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-15 12:47:44 +0000
Processing by HomeController#benefits as */*
  Rendered home/benefits.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 38 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 79ms (Views: 79.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: I suggest you read [Working with JavaScript in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have read that page many times but I think there is something fundamental I am not understanding about the javascript<->controller/action interaction.  I get this far and then I get stuck and I do not know how to debug it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. The issue is that you are calling a controller action with a `redirect_to` in it, which is where the

```
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

is coming from. If the ajax call gets a 302, you will have that issue.

Comment: I know I am missing a basic understanding to do with rendering. I was assuming that the redirect_to will then go to the other controller-action (which is what I want - and works with my non-Ajax button).  I do not understand where this breaks down when I use Ajax.  Any further pointer in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: Just do the ajax call on the controller action  that outputs a response

Comment: This did not seem to work.  To be sure I called a controller-action that has a view (and no redirect_to) called settings:index.   The webpage does not change and development.log shows this:          Rendered settings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (48.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 137ms (Views: 114.0ms | ActiveRecord: 22.0ms)

Comment: OK - but my web page still does not change from the current view to the settings/index view. Nothing appears to change.  Even though the development.log is saying it has rendered OK.

Comment: Are you just trying to do a redirect in Javascript?

Comment: From my current page I want to create an onchange event on a pulldown menu via JS that calls the same controller-action code that generated my current page. (Specific parts of the current webpage should update). I have some logic in my controller that needs to be executed to update some information.   So the problem I have is this:  I can add a button in HTML that calls that controller action no problem: User changes the pulldown menu, clicks the button and no problem. I want to do this via JS so button is NOT needed:  User changes menu option, controller-action gets called & info is updated.